# Batch file to rename with 3 digit incrementations

Tags: batch-file, rename

Here is my situation. I have a folder of images that i update almost daily. I want the bat file to rename them with the same name + a 3 digit incrementation.

```
anatomy 001.jpg
anatomy 002.jpg
anatomy 003.jpg
```

And that every time i add new files to the folder and run the batch file, it keeps the incrementation growing.

Here is what i have so far, picking from here and there and trying to understand what each function is doing ( i'm new to this field )

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set name=Anatomy
set /a index=0
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b /a-d *.jpg') do (
set index=!index!
set /a index+=1
ren "%%~i" "%name%!index!.jpg"
)
```

But my batch file is only incrementing with one digit and when i launch it again, it's renaming again the already renamed files, so anatomy002 could become anatomy007.

I'd need a command that tells to not rename already named files, or to not renamed files starting by " anatomy ". I'd also fix the 3 digit incrementation issue. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
set "name=Anatomy"
set /a index=1000000
for /f "tokens=2delims=. " %%i in ('dir /b /a-d /on "%sourcedir%\%name% *.jpg"') do (
 SET /a index=999000+1%%i
)

for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\*.jpg"^|findstr /r /i /v /c:"%name% ...\.jpg"') do (
 set /a index+=1
 ECHO ren "%sourcedir%\%%~i" "%name% !index:~-3!.jpg"
)
GOTO :EOF
```

I used a directory `u:\sourcedir` for my testing.

The first `for` locates existing `name nnn.jpg` files, sorted in order of name. Using dot and space as delimiters, the second token will be the sequence-number. Prepend this with `1` gives a sensible decimal number, and add 999000 gives 1000000+the last-number-used.

Then look in the directory again, but filter out (`/v`) without regard to case (`/i`) any name matching the regular expression (`/r`) the string (`/c:`) name+space+3characters+a dot (`\.`)jpg
and for each of *those* found, bump the counter and rename the file with the assigned name+space+the last 3 characters from the new index.jpg

The required REN commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO REN` to `REN` to actually rename the files.